# Integrals of rapidly oscillating phase functions.

Tags: integration, intuition, oscillatory-integral

Why is it the case that if the integrand of a given integral is rapidly oscillating, then all the contributions to the integral cancel out apart from where the function is *stationary*?

For example, consider an integral of the form $$I=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}F(x)e^{i\phi(x)}dx$$ where $\phi(x)$ is a rapidly oscillating function. As I've read, the only non-trivial contributions to this integral will be about the point where $\phi(x)$ is *stationary*, say at $x=x_{s}$, such that we can approximate the integral as $$I\simeq F(x_{s})e^{i\phi(x_{s})}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{i\phi''(x_{s})(x-x_{s})^{2}/2}=\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{i\phi''(x_{s})}}F(x_{s})e^{i\phi(x_{s})}$$ I believe this is known as the "*Method of Stationary Phase*".

Is the intuition that, because the integrand is rapidly oscillating, the neighbouring contributions to the integral will cancel one another out (since the integrand will be oscillating sinusoidally, if it is doing so rapidly, then neighbouring phases $\phi(x)$ will vary rapidly in value, and so neighbouring values of the integrand $F(x)e^{i\phi(x)}$ will cancel one another out on average), however, at the stationary point of the phase $\phi(x)$ (within the integration region), i.e. the point at which $\phi'(x)=0$, the phase won't be changing very much, and so contributions near this region will be "*in phase*", thus adding up instead of cancelling one another?!

Furthermore, if the integrand is oscillating, but *not* rapidly, then this cancellation will not occur, since neighbouring values will not necessarily negate one another (since the oscillations will be sinusoidal, if it is oscillating slowly, then neighbouring phases $\phi(x)$ will not necessarily differ much in value and so won't necessarily cancel out on average)?!

Comment: Have a look at the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma

Comment: @RonGordon Thanks for the link. What is the intuition for it though? Is any of what I wrote in the last to paragraphs of my OP correct at all?! Does one simply note that since the function is oscillating sinusoidally, the contributions from its peaks and troughs will cancel each other out if it has a large frequency, since then the neighbouring peaks and troughs will be so close together that they will cancel one another out, i.e. neighbouring values of the integrand $F(x)e^{i\phi(x)}$ will cancel?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to use the more general steepest descent method, as in general there may not be such stationary purely imaginary points on the real axis. The general method is to deform the contour so that it picks up points in the complex plane where you do have such stationary phases. For each such point you rewrite the integral by performing a conformal transform such that the exponential becomes exactly $\exp(-w^2)$ this then gets multiplied by the Jacobian $\frac{dz}{dw}$, expanding this factor is series then yields an asymptotic series. So, each saddle point then yields an asymptotic series that all contribute to the integral.

The expansion parameter is then $\epsilon$ when you replace $\phi(x)$ by $\frac{\phi(x)}{\epsilon}$. So, it's wise to put in this $\epsilon$ and then consider the convergence for $\epsilon = 1$. In general, asymptotic series will start to diverge after a number of terms that decreases with $\epsilon$. The best approximation is obtained by truncating the series after the smallest term. This is called the superasymptotic approximation, the remainder term is then of the form $\exp\left(-\frac{a}{\epsilon^b}\right)$, which is beyond all orders in $\epsilon$. There exists specialized methods to go beyond the asymptotically method, which involves resumming the divergent tail.

Comment: Ah, I see. thanks for informing me of this. To be honest, I was really trying to get some intuition for what is going on in the stationary phase approximation. Is any of what I wrote in the last two paragraphs of my OP a correct heuristic understanding at all?

Comment: Yes, and it's clearer if you imagine that there is an invisible $\Lambda$ that is multiplying $\phi(x)$ which happens to be equal to 1. The larger $\Lambda$ is, the more important the effects become are that you mentioned about why the stationary phase approximation works. But formally, nothing stops you from inserting $\Lambda = 1$ in the large $\Lambda$ expansion. So, the issues about whether or not $\phi(x)$ is going to oscillate fast enough etc. are going to boil down to examining the remainder term for $\Lambda = 1$.

Comment: Ah ok. So as $\Lambda$ becomes larger and larger, the oscillations become more and more rapid, and so the phases at neighbouring points become more and more out of phase, such that on average, neighbouring contributions cancel one another out (since the phase rapidly oscillates between positive and negative values). The dominant contribution to the integral then occurs in the region where the change in the phase is minimal, i.e. around the point of stationary phase. Would this be a correct understanding?!

Comment: Would it also be correct to say that when the integrand is less rapidly oscillating, phases at neighbouring points are less out of phase and so their contributions become more important, not cancelling out on average (since the value of the phase is not varying so rapidly and hence neighbouring values of phase are closer in value - instead of being almost in anti-phase, they add together more coherently)?!

Comment: @user35305 Yes, that's right, when the phase varies less rapidly, they add up more in a coherent way, you can see that by going beyond the leading contribution that you calculated, the next order term is relatively smaller than the leading term and becomes smaller the larger you choose $\Lambda$.

Comment: Ok cool, I think it makes more sense now, thanks for your help! Sorry to go on, but just to check, is the reason why the contributions away from the point of stationary phase contribute less and less to the integral as $\Lambda$ increases because neighbouring values of the phase become more and more out of phase (that is, nearby phases oscillate very rapidly between positive and negative values, and these positive and negative contributions cancel one another out on average)?!

Comment: Yes, by increasing $\Lambda$ you amplify the out of phase effects. So, the best way to estimate the integral is to also calculate a few of the higher order terms as a function of $\Lambda$ and then see if for $\Lambda = 1$ the higher order terms are smaller.

Comment: Ok cool, I think I get it now. Thanks for your help!